# How do i adjust my textarea to fit its content

Tags: html

I have a textarea that displays information from my database. How do i adjust the textarea to equally fit the size of the content from the database.

```
<textarea  type="" name="comment[]" value="<?php echo $row['comment'];?>" readonly><?php echo $row['comment'];?></textarea>
```

Comment: How are you wanting to adjust it?  Width wise, height wise?  Most browsers have a handle so the user can adjust to their preference.  If you want it only for layout, set with inline css `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 1):

Without the use of at least some javascript I do not think this is possible. However, a believe you can find a solution for your question here:

http://www.impressivewebs.com/textarea-auto-resize/

Here is an example using jQuery:

```
$('#content').on( 'change keyup keydown paste cut', 'textarea', function () {
    $(this).height(0).height(this.scrollHeight);
}).find( 'textarea' ).change();
```

Although you may need to edit a bit to support text coming from the database.

Another solution is you could use a div with "contenteditable" attribute, this will grow automatically however it will not be treated as a form value and will need some additional code if you need to send this data back to the server.

Comment: link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: @pipedreams2 how is it posibly done with javascript?

Comment: @pipedreams2 i have tried this particular example and it didnt work. i cant really tell the reason being the content from the database.

Answer (score 1):

you could achive this with JS, elastic is a good library for this:

http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/